# What does this mean? Initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Tags: iphone, xcode, sqlite

I'm trying to load text from sqlite database in detailed view and I'm getting this error.

Initialization discards qualifiers from pointer target type.

What does this mean? and how can I fix it. Help please. Here is my code.

```
-(void) hydrateDetailViewData {
        if (isDetailViewHydrated) return; 

        if (detailStmt == nil) {
                const char *sql = "Select ClubAddress from clubNames Where clubID = ?";
                 if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &detailStmt, NULL) !=SQLITE_OK)
                         NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating detail view statment. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
                 }
        sqlite3_bind_int(detailStmt, 1, clubID);

        if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(detailStmt)) {
                char *db_text = sqlite3_column_text(detailStmt, 2); //error showing here
                NSString *address = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: db_text];
                self.ClubAddress = address;
        }
        else
                NSAssert1(0, @"Error while getting the address of club. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        sqlite3_reset(detailStmt);

        isDetailViewHydrated = YES;
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sqlite3_column_text` is declared to return a `const unsigned char *`, and you are assigning it to a variable of type `char *`. This loses the `const` qualifier, so the compiler is warning you of that fact.

Comment: When I add const char I get the following error "Pointer targets in initialization differ in signedness" and the app crashes. The debug is also showing that it now longer picks up the database items. Any help.@Anomie

Comment: @wayne: That warning is because `const char *` is a pointer to signed characters (i.e. holding values from -128 to 127), while `const unsigned char *` is a pointer to unsigned characters (i.e. holding values from 0 to 255).

Comment: Any idea how I can fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

this will also work:

```
char* foo = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
NSString* Foo = (foo) ? [NSString stringWithUTF8String:foo] : @"";
```